# vb.net sub(sender e as object, e as eventargs)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

for a random sub like this

```
Protected Sub SStyleUnlock(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    HistValHighS.Enabled = True
    HistValMedS.Enabled = True
    HistValLowS.Enabled = True
    PeerValHighS.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

things like HistValHighS are textboxes.
Can I say that if I take off "sender As Object, e As EventArgs", everything would be the same?
In other word, it's always right to use Protected Sub (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) when only Protected Sub() is needed?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event handlers are usually Private, not Protected. There is a [relaxed delegate conversion feature of VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531336.aspx), which allows you to omit those parameters, if you never use them. There is a caveat however - if your event handler can be navigated via form designer, it will not know about your event handler, unless there is a 100% match in parameters. So it will create a new handler for you. If you are okay with this inconvenience, feel free to delete those parameters.